# SQL GROUP BY and kind of rereduce afterwards

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, reduce

I'm using PostgreSQL v.11. I have a table with 3 columns. My goal is to find redundancy inside data.

First of all, I do a simple GROUP BY:

```
SELECT client, block, "date"
FROM lines
GROUP BY client, block, "date"
ORDER BY client, block
```

The result looks like this:

```
1 | P10001 | 2020-01-01
1 | P10002 | 2020-04-17
1 | P10002 | 2020-05-04
1 | P10003 | 2020-05-05
```

Now I would like to identify rows that have the same "block", but different "date". In this example, this is the case for row 2 and 3 (block = P10002)

For now, I use javascript to parse the complete resultset and find these 2 redundant rows (I use `result.reduce(...)`)

But is there a way, in pure SQL, to extract this "rereduced" result?

The expected result is this:

```
1 | P10002 | 2020-04-17
1 | P10002 | 2020-05-04
```

It should be great to keep the two dates in the resultset, because I need to change the "block" for only one of them. If I don't have the date column in the resultset, I will need to do a second request to find all the affected rows.

Here is a script for the table and data

```
CREATE TABLE lines (
  "client" integer NOT NULL,
  "block" text NOT NULL,
  "date" date NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO lines ("client", "block", "date") VALUES
  (1, 'P10001', '2020-01-01'),
  (1, 'P10002', '2020-04-17'),
  (1, 'P10002', '2020-05-04'),
  (1, 'P10003', '2020-05-05');
```

Many thanks

Comment: So what exactly is the output you are looking for?

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL v11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `EXISTS`:

```
select l.* from lines l
where exists (
  select 1 from lines
  where client = l.client and block = l.block and date <> l.date
)
```

If there is no case of duplicate dates for each `client, block` you could also use `COUNT(*)` window function:

```
select client, block, date
from (
  select *, count(*) over (partition by client, block) counter
  from lines
) t
where counter > 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e53c7ea32169cf0c16bf6b96f32f6034).
Results:

```
> client | block  | date      
> -----: | :----- | :---------
>      1 | P10002 | 2020-04-17
>      1 | P10002 | 2020-05-04
```

Comment: Cool, it seems to work! Do you know if there's a performance cost (compared to a GROUP BY solution) if the table has million of rows?

Comment: If you use GROUP BY... you don't get full rows but only `client, block` unless you use it as a subquery to another select statement. So what do you need? Full rows with dates or just `client, block`? About the performance you will have to test it. EXISTS performs really fast because it does not have to scan the while table but returns as soon as it finds a match. If there is no case for duplicate dates for each `client, block` there is also a solution with window functions if you are interested.

Comment: What I need exactly is `client, block, date` grouped by `client, block` but only for groups which has more than one date. After that, I need to change the `block`, because a same `block` cannot have multiple dates

Comment: In a statement with `GROUP BY client, block` you don't get in the results `client, block, date` with all the different dates included. You only get `client, block`.

Comment: After digging a bit more, your answer is definitely the one I need, many thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `HAVING` clause along with `GROUP`ing `BY block` as distinctly counting the `dates` :

```
SELECT block
  FROM lines
 GROUP BY block
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT "date" ) > 1;


block
------
P10002
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `HAVING`clause to get the redundant datasets. I assume you need the client as well in the redundancy detection.

The query looks like this.

```
SELECT client, block
FROM lines
GROUP BY client, block
HAVING count(distinct "date") > 1
ORDER BY client, block
```

Comment: This solution is very interesting too, and works as expected if we add MAX(date) in the select clause. Do you know if there's a performance cost compared to "forpas" solution?

Comment: In "forpas" EXISTS solution I see a potential performance issue because it performs a self-join which may be costly when the table is large. The other solution with the `partition by` might not work for all DBMS.

Comment: Thanks. In fact, you two gave answers that suit my needs. For now, "forpas" is quicker and I do only one DB access. With your GROUP BY, it may be better performant with huge table, which is not my case... right now ;-) I definitely keep these two answers in my mind. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This works in all database management systems.

Some DBMSs (you don't specify) also offer `GROUP BY ROLLUP()`. Look that up in your DBMS's docu.

As said, this one works everywhere - they might sort NULLs differently.

```
WITH
lines(client,block,dt) AS (
          SELECT 1,'P10001',DATE '2020-01-01'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'P10002',DATE '2020-04-17'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'P10002',DATE '2020-05-04'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'P10003',DATE '2020-05-05'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'P10001',DATE '2020-01-01'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'P10002',DATE '2020-04-17'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'P10002',DATE '2020-05-04'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'P10003',DATE '2020-05-05'
)
SELECT
  client
, block
, dt
FROM lines
UNION ALL
SELECT
  client
, block
, NULL::DATE AS dt
FROM lines
GROUP BY
  client
, block
ORDER BY
  client
, block
, dt
-- out  client | block  |     dt     
-- out --------+--------+------------
-- out       1 | P10001 | 
-- out       1 | P10001 | 2020-01-01
-- out       1 | P10001 | 2020-01-01
-- out       1 | P10002 | 
-- out       1 | P10002 | 2020-04-17
-- out       1 | P10002 | 2020-04-17
-- out       1 | P10002 | 2020-05-04
-- out       1 | P10002 | 2020-05-04
-- out       1 | P10003 | 
-- out       1 | P10003 | 2020-05-05
-- out       1 | P10003 | 2020-05-05
```